# How to set Notifications Service Extension in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, notificationservices

I'm using normal notifications service extension to auto increase notification number means that without using MORichNotification, CTNotificationService, or something else.

Just going to New -> target -> notification service extension -> create NotificationService -> active

Then, set NotificationService deployment target to 10.3 while project deployment target is 11.0

In FCM payload I set like:

```
{
    "to" : " device token/ firebase topic",
    "notification" : {
      "body" :  "body",
      "title" : "FCM Notification"
     },
    "mutable_content": true
  }
```

I also enable push notification in NotificationService target and Select it before run in my device but, still Unable to use Notification service extension.

Am I did something wrong?
Should I use  MORichNotification or anything like that?

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you figured this out?